# Using URL Rewrites to allow 1 IP address to host two subdomains

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a scenario where I need to two different subdomains to come through the firewall and be rewritten or redirected to areas on the server.  For example if I have sub1.mydomain.com/testsub1.html  entered externally, I want it to hit the IIS "Default web site/folders/sub1/testsub1.html" and likewise, if  sub2.mydomain.com/testsub2.html is received I want it to go to "Default web site/folders/sub2/testsub2.html".  We were told that URL Rewritew would be the way to go on this.  So we set up rules in the Default web site, to use the MatchURL pattern for:
1. sub1.mydomain.com(.*) and to rewrite it to "Default web site/folders/sub1(R:1)" with the action type of Rewrite. 
2. sub2.mydomain.com(.*) and to rewrite it to "Default web site/folders/sub2(R:1)" with the action type of Rewrite.

If I hit http://sub1.mydomain.com/testsub1.html, I get a file not found error.  What I am seeing in the logs is the GET /testsub1.html.  If I change the URL to http://sub1.mydomain.com/folders/sub1/testsub1.html, it works perfectly and I see GET /folders/sub1/testsub1.html in the logs and the proper page is displayed in the browser.

What am I missing to make this work without the full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are the best way to handle this. They can listen on the same IP address for different hostnames. Create two separate websites in IIS and configure each of their bindings for that particular subdomain.

More information: http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx